# Git hook to mirror repository from Server A to Server B

Tags: git, gitlab

I have git repository on gitlab server. However, I would like to mirror the git repository from Server A to Server B (which is remote server). I am able to mirror the repository using following command:

```
git push --mirror http://example.com/test-repo.git
```

I would like to use the hook which should get executed after `git push` command. Which will run the above command.

I have tried adding post-receive post-update hooks in my repository but doesn't execute it.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Note: I need this for backup purpose, if we push any changes on server A it will be replicated to remote server B at the same time.

Comment: if it doesn't execute the hooks you haven't configured them correctly. How did you install them? Did you follow the steps at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/custom_hooks.html or https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gitlab has a [Repository Mirroring](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/workflow/repository_mirroring.html) feature. Push is in the open source available. 
If you need pull then you have to get the EE version.